# Redux store stops receiving actions when changing to another browser tab

Tags: reactjs, redux, service-worker, browser-tab

I'm using React 16.8.6 with redux 4.0.1 but I have a problem with the store of redux.
The store stops dispatching any action when I change to another browser tab.

**Normal flow:**

1. *Clic a button*
2. Action 1 dispatched (fetch something)
3. Action 2 dispatched (save something in DB)
4. Action 3 dispatched (fetch something)

**When I change to another tab:**

1. *Clic a button*
2. Action 1 dispatched (fetch something)
3. *Change to other browser tab or open other application*
4. *(App receives no other action)*

But when I go back to my app's tab and refresh it, I can see the changes that **action 1** and **2** are supposed to do. However, they were not catched by my app because its tab was not active.

Since the app is using firebase messaging, I was tryng to connect it with the React service worker in order to solve the problem but it doesn't work.

What do you thing should I do ? Is this a common problem with redux ?

Comment: is there any solution you found. Please update.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a persistence redux state with some libraries like (This approach works when you share state between two tabs as well) [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist), for another hand if you want to implement your own library you can use a persistence system like local/session storage, Redux, rabbitMQ, etc, and in this posts have some good ideas [Sharing state between tabs](https://medium.com/@daverivera90/sharing-state-between-browser-tabs-with-redux-68899eb88fb7)